# Proof that $(\nabla\nabla s)(X,Y)=\nabla_X\nabla_Y s-\nabla_{\nabla_XY}s$

Tags: riemannian-geometry, connections

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold and $\nabla$ a covariant derivative on a vector bundle $E$. In [Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators](https://link.springer.com/book/9783540200628) the connection Laplacian $\Delta$ is defined by
$$\Delta=-\mathrm{Tr}(\nabla^2):=-\mathrm{Tr}(\nabla^{T^*M\otimes E}\nabla^E)$$
and it is said that
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
   (\nabla\nabla s)(X,Y)=\nabla_X\nabla_Ys-\nabla_{\nabla_XY}s.
\end{equation}
I think that this follows from the fact that for $T\in \Gamma(M,T^*M\otimes E)$ we have
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
   (\nabla T)(X,Y)=\nabla_X(T(Y))-T(\nabla_XY)
\end{equation}
as $(1)$ follows from $(2)$ by plugging in $T=\nabla s$.

In fact I believe that I have a proof of $(2)$. Nevertheless I would appreciate a confirmation that my reasoning and my proof are correct:

\begin{align}
    &(\nabla T)(X,Y)=(\nabla_XT)(Y)=\nabla_X(e^i\otimes T_i)(Y)&\\
    &=(e^i\otimes\nabla_X T{}_i)(Y)+((\nabla_X e{}^i)\otimes T_i)(Y)&\\
    &=e^i(Y)\nabla_X T_i+(\nabla_X e^i)(Y)T_i&\\
    &=e^i(Y)\nabla_X T_i+\mathrm{d}_X(e^i(Y))T_i-e^i(\nabla_X Y)T_i&\\
     &=Y^i\nabla_X T_i+\mathrm{d}_X(Y^i)T_i-T(\nabla_X Y)&\\
&=\nabla_X(Y^iT_i)-T(\nabla_X Y)=\nabla_X(T(Y))-T(\nabla_X Y)&
\end{align}

Comment: First of all, at least in [G], the definition should be $\Delta = -\mathop{\rm Tr} {\nabla^{T^*\otimes \cal E}\circ \nabla^{\cal E}}$ - agree?

Comment: As opposed to, $\nabla^2$, which for me at least, would mean extending the 'second' $\nabla$ by enforcing the Leibnitz rule: $\nabla (\omega\otimes s) = d\omega \otimes s - \omega \wedge \nabla s$ (with $\omega$ a 1-form).

Comment: @peterag I agree! Only Petersen writes $\nabla^2$ (page $209$).

Comment: By the by, IRC, $\nabla^*\nabla$ is how Roe denotes $\Delta$.

Comment: @Fillipo  just in case you didn't see (and sorry for the repeated pings, if you have), but the system moved everything over to the 'chat' below - please take a look at the extra comments in the chat.

Comment: @peterag "just in case you didn't see" - I didn't, thank you for the comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still only a comment - but continuing the above.

So : $\nabla^{T^*\otimes \cal E}(\omega \otimes s) = (\nabla^{T^*} \omega)\otimes s + \omega \otimes \nabla^{\cal E} s$. Be careful with the evaluation on vector fields:
$$\nabla^{T^*\otimes \cal E}(\omega \otimes s) (X,Y) = (\nabla^{T^*}_X \omega)(Y)s + \omega(Y) \nabla_X^{\cal E} s.\tag{*}$$

*Addendum*

Even though I think you had this earlier (from your eliminated comments),  and now have it above - I am adding this as promised:

By the product rule fiat/definition,
$$(\nabla_X \omega) (Y) = X (\omega (Y)) - \omega (\nabla_X Y).$$

Therefore, substituting into (*), one has

$$\nabla^{T^*\otimes \cal E}(\omega \otimes s) (X,Y) = {\Large(}X (\omega (Y))  - \omega (\nabla_X Y){\Large)} s + \omega(Y)  \nabla_X^{\cal E} s.$$
Rearranging and regrouping,
$$\nabla^{T^*\otimes \cal E}(\omega \otimes s) (X,Y) = {\Large(}X (\omega (Y))s + \omega(Y) \nabla_X^{\cal E} s {\Large)} - \omega (\nabla_X Y)s .$$

Therefore
$$\nabla^{T^*\otimes \cal E}(\omega \otimes s) (X,Y) = \nabla_X^{\cal E} (\omega (Y) s) - \omega (\nabla_X Y)s, $$

obtaining your desired expression for an elementary / decomposable tensor $\omega \otimes s$ .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145435/discussion-between-peter-a-g-and-filippo).